# Numpy vectorize numpy.dot function

Tags: python, numpy

I have `a=np.array([array([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]),array([6,7,8,9])])`. I want to take a dot product of both of the arrays with some vector v.

I tried to vectorize the np.dot function.

`vfunc=np.vectorize(np.dot)`  and I applied the vfunc to my array a. `vfunc(a,v)`where v is the vector i want to take dot product with. However, i get this error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` . Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You won't be able to vectorize this, since you have a jagged array. Also `np.vectorize` doesn't really *vectorize* operations

Comment: What's this other vector?  Shape?

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem here. Originally, array 'a' has numpy arrays of (n,5) shape and vector v has (5,1) shape.

Comment: @yatu Can you suggest me some other way that doesn't involve for loop?

Comment: The thing is that you cannot vectorize in numpy with jagged arrays. You need a homogeneous array, where all its elements are accessible via strides and offsets. Not possible with an array of arrays

Comment: Here, I have 2 objects inside an array. I want to  apply a same function to both of these objects. I tried and found that I can apply a function with single argument. If I am taking a dot product with a constant vector instead of some arbitrary vector, vectorize method works. I am trying to figure out how to make it work if it involves a arbitrary vector v. @yatu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing an object dtype array as argument, you need to specify 'O' result type as well.  Without `otypes` `vectorize` tries to deduce the return dtype, and may do so wrongly.  That's just one of the pitfalls to using `np.vectorize`:

```
In [196]: f = np.vectorize(np.dot, otypes=['O'])                                
In [197]: x = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]])                                     
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  #!/usr/bin/python3

In [199]: f(x, x)                                                               
Out[199]: array([14, 30], dtype=object)
```

Another problem with `np.vectorize` is that it is slower than alternatives:

```
In [200]: f1 = np.frompyfunc(np.dot, 2,1)                                       
In [201]: f1(x,x)                                                               
Out[201]: array([14, 30], dtype=object)

In [202]: np.array([np.dot(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,x)])                           
Out[202]: array([14, 30])

In [203]: timeit f(x, x)                                                        
27.1 µs ± 229 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
                                                                       
In [204]: timeit f1(x,x)                                                        
16.9 µs ± 135 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [205]: timeit np.array([np.dot(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,x)])                    
21.3 µs ± 201 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`np.vectorize` has a **clear** speed disclaimer.  Read the full docs; it isn't as simple a function as you might think.  The name can be misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, It's still not working when I try to take dot product of 'array ([array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[6, 4, 7],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [7, 2, 4]])], dtype=object)'
with another vector 'v=np.array([1,2,3])'. by dot product I mean element wise dot product where each element of the original array which is array itself gives the row wise dot product with the given vector v.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  Error?  wrong result?

Comment: If your function takes 2 arguments, then `np.vectorize` tries to iterate on the elements of both.  With that `v` it passes each element, 1,2,3, separately.  1 with the first subarray, 2 with the 2nd etc.  Like I wrote, `np.vectorize` is a lot trickier to use than a surface read of its docs implies.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a fully working example, both using a straight forward iteration, and a (failed) `np.vectorize`.  I'm still guessing about the full functionality that you need.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Instead of vector itself, i passed array of a vector such that it passed same vector to all the sub-array and it worked.